# What does actually happens if you delete the working directory, how the kernel handles that?

Tags: linux, unix, file-descriptor, cd, working-directory

I've trying to find this answer all over SO but didn't found one. Let's take an example first:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ mkdir foo
$ cd foo
$ pwd
/tmp/foo
$ $SHELL
$ rmdir /tmp/foo
$ exit
$ pwd
/tmp/foo
$ ls
<no output>
$ man ls
man: can't change directory to '': No such file or directory
man: command exited with status 255: (cd  && LESS=-ix8RmPm Manual page ls(1) ?ltline %lt?L/%L.:byte %bB?s/%s..?e (END):?pB %pB\%.. (press h for help or q to quit)$PM Manual page ls(1) ?ltline %lt?L/%L.:byte %bB?s/%s..?e (END):?pB %pB\%.. (press h for help or q to quit)$ MAN_PN=ls(1) pager -s)
$ echo -e '#include<unistd.h>\n#include<stdio.h>\n#include<stdlib.h>\nint main(){char*p=getcwd(NULL,0);printf("%s\\n",p);free(p);}' | gcc -x c -
/usr/bin/ld: cannot open output file a.out: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
$ cd $PWD
cd: no such file or directory: /tmp/foo
```

What's happening here *internally*? How does the kernel handle this kind of situations? If it's supposed that the current directory remains as a file descriptor, **why** does all those commands fail?

And, (at least for me) more importantly, why there's **no** protection against this kind of stuff? It appears to me that it can lead to serious security issues easily...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you remove a directory, the following steps take place:

- The link to the directory in its parent is removed
- The `..` link in the directory to its parent is removed
- The `.` link in the directory to itself is removed

As each of these takes place, the directory's link count is removed. When the link count becomes `0`, the directory itself is removed from the filesystem.

If there are any processes accessing the directory (either as a working directory, or because they've called `opendir()`), these will also increase the directory's link count. So the directory doesn't really go away until all these accesses go away.

While the directory is in this state, it can be read, but anything that depends on any of the above links will fail. When you do `cd $PWD`, it's trying to do `cd /tmp/foo`, but the `foo` link has been removed.

Comment: This doesn't explains why things like `man` or even `touch` fail.

Comment: The error message from `man` explain it: it's trying to change to the current directory, but the name doesn't exist.

Comment: "Switching to the current directory." - Isn't the process there already?

Comment: But it's trying to get there using a pathname. I don't know what's going on internally within `man`, you'd have to check the source code.